# Mobile Payment patent: Why is the last step of Claim 1 there? It seems to contradict the second to last step of Claim 1

Tags: claims, mobile

In this mobile payment patent: http://www.google.com/patents/US8639619, the last 2 steps of claim 1 are:

> providing the token and the payment amount to the payment-processing entity, via the communication module, to cause completion of a transaction between the user and the merchant,
>
> wherein providing the code or token alone does not enable completion of the transaction.

Why does the first step say "providing the token...to cause completion of a transaction" and the second step say "providing the code or token alone does not enable completion of the transaction"?

Having trouble understanding why the last part of claim 1 is there at all.

Answer (score 1):

The key is in "or."

> wherein providing the code **or** token alone does not enable completion of the transaction.

The token alone can't complete it, and the code alone can't complete it. You need to supply both.

When the token is supplied with the code, the server is aware of both, so the transaction is completed.

Comment: Do you mean that the "token" is the same as the "payment amount"?  In reading the rest of the patent, it seems the token, code, and payment amount, are 3 separate things.

Comment: @ChrisRichmond Oh, sorry, I meant to say "code." My bad. But yeah, I wasn't super clear from my admittedly quick glance what the differentiation between the three was. I think the code contains information (or a reference to information) about the payment amount, but I wasn't sure on that either.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that: token = returned from payment processor, references the payment instrument; code = generated by the server, sent to mobile device; payment amount = money the merchant wants to charge.